# How to change the text of the multiple asp:label using for loop in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, for-loop, label

I want to change the asp label multiple times.

Here is the asp.net code

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_Text1" runat="server" Text="">
<asp:Label ID="lbl_Text2" runat="server" Text="">
<asp:Label ID="lbl_Text3" runat="server" Text="">
<asp:Label ID="lbl_Text4" runat="server" Text="">
```

Instead of using this:

C# Code

```
lbl_Text1.Text = "hello";
lbl_Text2.Text = "hello";
lbl_Text3.Text = "hello";
lbl_Text4.Text = "hello";
```

I tried to use for loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    lbl_Text[i].Text = "hello";
}
```

And I get this error.....

> cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.label'

Is there anyone can help me on that?

Comment: I think you need to use FindControl
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
((Label)FindControl("lbl_Text" + i)).Text = "hello";
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by using [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
  var label = ((Label)FindControl("lbl_Text" + i));
  if(label != null){
     label.Text = "hello";
  }
}
```

Comment: I have this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @IrishChieftain nope. it has lbl_Text4 .

Comment: Can you show the page's code? All the controls are in the same page right? Not on usercontrol or masterpage?

Comment: @ysrb The code is in default.aspx.cs inherited from MasterPage.masterpage

Comment: @Minelava I need to see more code to be able to help you more. sorry. Can;t tell what's wrong at the moment.